# Kube behavior when more memory is required?

Tags: php, memory, kubernetes

This question is regarding the Kubernetes behavior when request need more memory than allocated to Pod containing php app . If GC is not able to free memory and request need more memory due to which pods becomes unresponsive or request gets timed out , will kube restart the pod in itself ?

In case swap memory is given, will kube try to use it before it restart the pod.

Comment: Have you read about [Configure Out of Resources Handling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/) in the docs?

Comment: and [Managing Compute Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap is not supported with Kubernetes and it will refuse to start if active. Request values for pod resources cannot be overcommitted so if a pod requests 1GB and no node has 1GB available (compared to total RAM minus the requests on all pods scheduled to that node) then the pod will remain unscheduled until something changes. Limits can be overcommitted, but Kubernetes is not involved in that process. It just sets the memory limit in the process cgroup. Out of memory handling works like it always does on Linux, if the kernel decides it is out of memory, then it triggers a thing called the `oomkiller` which ranks processes and kills the worst one.

Comment: Using swap is not recommended, running with swap is possible with the `kubelet` command line option `--fail-swap-on=false` or the equivalent [config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/)

Comment: Fair, I guessed that someone asking on SO probably shouldn't be using that kind of advanced option :)

Comment: @coderanger You said `Limits can be overcommitted, but Kubernetes is not involved in that process. It just sets the memory limit in the process cgroup` Does it mean if process required more memory than upper limit defined for pod then it will ask os(linux)  and os will provide if it has enoufg memory even if I have defined upper limit for pod ? Then what is the advantage of defining upper limit at pod level ?

Comment: I guess technically that’s possible, if there was a bug in the cgroups system? But there usually isn’t and Linux will respect the resource limits set in the cgroup for each container because thats what they are there for.

Comment: Looks like I was not clear in my previous question. My question is if I set the 2 GB limit for pod(containing one container), but due to more http request from user, somehow it needs more than 2GB, in that case what will kube do ? From your answer looks like, it will pass on the control to kernel, which will decide which particular process with in that container needs to be killed based on cgroup setting and ranking. Is that correct ?

Comment: That is correct, after the initial launch, Kubernetes is not involved. Out-of-memory detection and killing are Linux-level features, not K8s :)